# How to compile FFMPEG with h.265, h.264 and vp9 support on CentOS

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos

I was using this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos instructions to get through the process but ran into errors.

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.31611 (Core)
```

What failed was the configuration and the build of the libx264. The output of the process is

```
$:~/ffmpeg_sources/x264$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-static
Found no assembler
Minimum version is nasm-2.13
```

full output here https://pastebin.com/qjwpdvc9.

Starting the available assemblers from the commandline showed this

```
[wolke3/steffenr]:~/ffmpeg_sources/x264$ nasm -v && yasm --version
NASM version 2.10.07 compiled on Jun  9 2014
yasm 1.2.0
Compiled on Feb 17 2014.
Copyright (c) 2001-2011 Peter Johnson and other Yasm developers.
Run yasm --license for licensing overview and summary.
```

https://pastebin.com/9Td5tA1a

I then installed the latest nasm with

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://www.nasm.us/nasm.repo
yum install nasm
```

It seems I still miss something. I can now use the nasm, but the linking fails. I guess I'm missing some libraries. 
Please see output here https://pastebin.com/KTwvMS9i

I ended up using the provided procompiled binaries but I'd rather build `ffmpeg`on my own.

Any advice?

Comment: Hm. I went through the entire guide again with a fresh install of CentOS and got it to work. Not sure where your particular error comes from.

Comment: The inclusion of the nasm repo was the only necessary change. It turned out that I had some libavcode.a in /usr/local/lib from a former try to build ffmpeg. After I deleted those I could run through the CompilationGuide with much success. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok! Undeleted my answer in case you'd like to accept that.

Comment: It will be my pleasure, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install the latest nasm version using `yum` by adding the repository:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://www.nasm.us/nasm.repo
```

Then:

```
yum install nasm
```

This gives you nasm ≥ 2.13.

With this, the rest of the ffmpeg guide should work. I updated the guide on the FFmpeg Wiki, too.

Comment: Damn... www.nasm.us seems to be dead :(

Comment: @Julian Up now.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to compile things yourself:

```
curl -LO https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.13.01/nasm-2.13.01.tar.gz
tar xzvf nasm-2.13.01.tar.gz 
cd nasm-2.13.01
./configure --prefix=/opt/nasm
make
sudo make install
export PATH=/opt/nasm/bin/:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issues with getting the repository of `nasm` and its installation with `yum`. The [official nasm installation](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/nasm.html) is recommended. That guaranty the nasm installation with its desired version.